# How to prove a gradient is Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, lipschitz-functions

I have read in textbooks the following phrase, "assuming the gradient is locally Lipschitz continuous...", but how does one prove that the gradient is locally Lipschitz continuous?

If we have a continuously differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, from looking at previous stackexchange questions on this topic it seems we can show the gradient is Lipschitz continuous via Taylor's formula, but was wondering if anyone has insight or can point to papers/resources that clarify this further. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible, even for twice differentiable functions, to have a gradient that isn't locally Lipschitz. Namely, the function $g(t)=\begin{cases}t\lvert t\rvert^{1/2}\cos\frac1t&\text{if }t\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }t=0\end{cases}$ is differentiable with derivative $g'(t)=\begin{cases}\lvert t\rvert^{1/2}\cos \frac1t-\frac{\lvert t\rvert^{1/2}}{t}\sin\frac1t&\text{if }t\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }t=0\end{cases}$, which  is unbounded in all neighbourhoods of $0$. Since a differentiable function $g:I\to\Bbb R$ is Lipschitz if and only if its derivative is bounded, $g$ isn't locally Lipschitz.  $g$ is itself the derivative of the function $G(x)=\int_0^x g(t)\,dt$, which ends up being a twice-differentiable counterexample to your claim for $n=1$. For $n>1$, consider $f(x)=G(x_1)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I see now that not all differentiable functions have locally Lipschitz gradients. But what about for functions which _do_ have locally Lipschitz gradients, how can we show this is the case? How can we show that its derivative is bounded?